# jQuery plugin disappearing after page load

Tags: jquery, treetable

I'm loading the treeTable jQuery plugin with the page and using it like so:

```
jQuery('#tablename').treeTable();
```

And it works just fine. Now, if I click a button and run that exact same line a second time, I get an error telling me that there is no method called 'treeTable'. If I simply copy and paste the line to run multiple times during load, they work fine, so the problem only appears after the whole page has been ingested into the DOM. Now, I can successfully run the code again if I assign the treeTable to a variable, and run it again like so:

During page load:

```
var treetable = jQuery('#tablename').treeTable();
```

After button click:

```
treetable.treeTable();
```

That works fine. It would be a workable solution, if not for my need to use other methods in the treeTable plugin on dynamically loaded elements (I don't know the generated ids ahead of time, and thus can't create placeholder objects to call on them). So I need to figure out why the treeTable plugin seems to be disappearing after the page is done loading.

My setup actually works perfectly in my little test-environment, this problem only happens when I integrate my page into a larger website. The only other jQuery plugins in use on the larger site are ui, dataTables, and multiSelector.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned you are dynamically generating elements...  could it be that because the items are added after the fact that its not finding your new elements?

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later perhaps trying something like :

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".btnClass", function(){
    jQuery('#tablename').treeTable();
)};
```

If you are using jQuery 1.3-1.6 or later perhaps trying something like :

```
jQuery(".btnClass").bind("click",function(){
    jQuery('#tablename').treeTable();
)};
```